# How arrange divs in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

How to solve problem that converting html to pdf leads to organizing divs one under the other? I want to maintain the orginal arrangement of divs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your code is responsive?

Comment: @lazzy_ms yep, it is. So there is also problem with too low image resolution when the screen is too thin.

Comment: can you post the code?